# Custom kernel rpm fails to install due to conflicts with kernel-firmware package

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have basically made a custom kernel on CentOS 6 using source from kernel.org.

This modified kernel works fine. However, now I want to create an rpm for this kernel.

I used make rpm option in kernel source tree.
However, if I try to install this on another machine I hit a lot of conflicts with kernel-firmware package.

```
rpm -ivh /media/sf_VMShare/kernel-3.10.19-17.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    file /lib/firmware/3com/typhoon.bin from install of kernel-3.10.19-17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch
    file /lib/firmware/acenic/tg1.bin from install of kernel-3.10.19-17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch
    file /lib/firmware/acenic/tg2.bin from install of kernel-3.10.19-17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch
    file /lib/firmware/adaptec/starfire_rx.bin from install of kernel-3.10.19-17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch
    file /lib/firmware/adaptec/starfire_tx.bin from install of kernel-3.10.19-17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch
```

It seems almost everything in `/lib/firmware` conflicts. I have trimmed the output down. What is a possible solution for this? I tried installing the matching kernel-firmware package from the machine where this rpm is being made. But that doesn't help.

Comment: This is possibly an issue with older kernel versions like kernel-2.6.32.

Comment: ok. should i try kernel-firmware-3 version ?

Comment: Yes I think you should try with newer kernel version. This bug is fixed in the newer kernels. A similar issue is mentioned over here https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicallly removing the conflicting kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.el6.noarch allows kernel installation to go through.